# How to add specific task from my common azure yml template? azure yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

**Problem to solve**: I have my common template which contain more then 5 tasks, like this:

```
-Task 1
-Task 2
...
- Task5
```

**Possible solution:** I want to refer that template which is in another repository; but I don't want to refer all 5 tasks, I just want to refer Task-1 not all 5

Problem of the solution: I want to know how I can re-use only 1 Task from another repository, not whole template

I have tried:

```
- template:myyaml..yml@alias name
```

But it calls my all 5 tasks, whereas I just want to refer one task only.

Comment: Please check the following answers if they can help you. If there is a correct answer for you, please mark it as a right answer so that it can help more persons who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to split your common yaml file that contains multiple tasks into several yaml files that contain a single task. You can then reference the individual task templates that you actually require in your main yaml file.

For example, split your single common template into multiple files like below

```yaml
# File: template1.yml
steps:
- script: echo this is one templated task
```

```yaml
# File: template2.yml
steps:
- script: echo this is another templated task
```

Then pick what ones you want to use in your main yaml file like so

```yaml
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

steps:
# Pick what templated tasks you want to use here
- template: template1.yml@templates  # Template reference
- template: twmplate2.yml@templates  # Template reference
```